# Can't connect to MySQL after server maintenance

Tags: database, laravel

My Host moved my app to another server since then, I have been battling with this error. `can't connect to server on 127.0.0.1`

Please, how can I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: Please show your .env code for database

Comment: Looks like there's no DB running on your localhost. I'd contact your hosting provider.

Comment: If you're running locally you need to start your mysql server. If this is on a server you need to speak with your host provider as @ajt said. If you're hosting on your own dedi server you need to check the mysql is running and confirm the port numbers havent been changed from default.

Answer (score 0):

From the database.php config,

```
'mysql' => [
    ...
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    ...
],
```

You will need to look at your .env file. Look for the DB_HOST variable. If it's not there, your database config defaults back to 127.0.0.1

Comment: the details are OK. i guess is from my host. Thanks